# How to refactor common fields, properties in two classes/interfaces in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Is there a way to pull up common methods, properties etc. just by name (maybe even signature too) into a common class from 2 or more classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract some members from a single class to a base class as in this [documentation link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Refactorings__Extract_Superclass.html) from Resharper 2016.2, but detect the common properties and methods seems to be  a very tricky thing to do without any input from the developer.

There is a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-276474) in Jetbrains' backlog asking for something like that since 2014, but the [linked SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415869/create-a-superclass-from-multiple-classes-that-have-common-members) question states the same I'm telling you. Maybe you want to take a look at it too.